# Dataflow works with directrunner but not with dataflowrunner (PubSub to GCS)

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm doing a very simple pipeline with dataflow.

It gets a raw data from pubsub and adds a timestamp then write to raw file (I tried parquet first).

Code:

```
class GetTimestampFn(beam.DoFn):
    """Prints element timestamp"""
    def process(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
        timestamp_utc = float(timestamp)
        yield {'raw':str(element),"inserted_at":timestamp_utc}


options = PipelineOptions(streaming=True)
p = beam.Pipeline(DirectRunner(), options=options)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input_topic',required=True)
parser.add_argument('--output_parquet',required=True)
known_args, _ = parser.parse_known_args(argv)


raw_data = p | 'Read'  >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_topic) 
raw_with_timestamp = raw_data | 'Getting Timestamp' >> beam.ParDo(GetTimestampFn())
_ = raw_with_timestamp | 'Write' >> beam.io.textio.WriteToText(known_args.output_parquet,append_trailing_newlines=True
    ,file_name_suffix='.gzip'
)

p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

It works with direct runner but  it fails on dataflowrunner with this message "Workflow failed."

Job id: 2021-04-14_17_11_02-16453427249129279174

How I'm running the job:

```
python  real_time_events.py \
--region us-central1 \
--input_topic 'projects/{project}/subscriptions/{subscription}' \
--output_parquet 'gs://{bucket}/stream/' \
--project "{project}" \
--temp_location "gs://{bucket}/tmp" \
--staging_location "gs://{bucket}/stage"
```

Any ideas on how to solve ?

Comment: Try by adding --save_main_session in arguments

Comment: Thanks, just tried that still same error.

Answer (score 0):

`WriteToText` does not support streaming pipelines. I recommend you try using `fileio.WriteToFiles` instead, to get a transform that supports streaming. Note that you may need to group before it.